# JavaScript using Intersection observer Ul list continuous scroll

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I am trying to scroll Unorder List `ul' continuously in cyclic using Intersection Observer.

On Scroll to the last `li` append the first `li` element to the `ul`. If scroll to the top `li`  prepend last `li` to the top.

javascript code  and [codepen link](https://codepen.io/B-L-Praveen/pen/KKbqMyr)

```js
// callback function to be run whenever a threshold is crossed in one direction or the other

const target = document.querySelector('.hour li:last-child');
const callback = (entries, observer) => {
   const node = document.querySelector(".hour").firstElementChild;
   document.querySelector(".hour").append(node);
  
}

// options lets you control the circumstances under which the observer's callback is invoked
const options = {
  // no root provided - by default browser viewport used to check visibility of target
  // Uncomment below if you want the nav bar to change background color as soon as content div is scrolled
  rootMargin: "-10px 0px 0px 0px",
  // only detect if visibility of target element is 100% or not
  threshold: [1]
};

// create intersection observer
const io = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
io.observe(target);
// observe content div
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use can use scroll event instead of observer to achieve a cyclic scroll

Also your codepen has typo in li, I had tested in Chrome latest.

```js
document.getElementById('hour').onscroll = e=>{
    const height = e.target.scrollHeight - e.target.clientHeight;
    const scrollHeight = e.target.scrollTop;
    const percent = (height/100);
    const top = percent*20;
    const bottom = percent*80;
    if(scrollHeight > bottom){
        e.target.append(e.target.firstElementChild);
    }else if(scrollHeight < top){
        e.target.prepend(e.target.lastElementChild)
    }
}
```

```css
.hour {
  list-style-type: none;
  height:100px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  width:60px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="hour" class='hour'>
 <li>24</li><li>01
  </li><li>02
  </li><li>03
  </li><li>04
  </li><li>05
  </li><li>06
  </li><li>07
  </li><li>08
  </li><li>09
  </li><li>10
  </li><li>11
  </li><li>12
  </li><li>13
  </li><li>14
  </li><li>15
  </li><li>16
  </li><li>17
  </li><li>18
  </li><li>19
  </li><li>20
  </li><li>21
  </li><li>22
  </li><li>23
  </li></ul>
```

Comment: onscroll works only when you scroll down. prepend will not work

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Edge Browser using

Comment: It work's fine for me in latest edge browser